# IndexOf does not return any value in c#

Tags: c#, string, indexof

It may seem a duplicate question, but it is not.

I have a simple code. There is a string named `book` with the value of `"mybook"`.
I want to find the index of `'y'` character in `"mybook"` string. So I used this code but it did not return the index of the `'y'` character.

```
string book = "mybook";
char y = 'y';
int yPosition = book.IndexOf(y);

Console.WriteLine("y position is: ", yPosition);
```

When I run this code, the answer is this and nothing more:

```
y position is:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the include where the formatted element will be included in your format string.

If you change

```
Console.WriteLine("y position is: ",yPosition);
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine("y position is: {0}",yPosition);
```

you should get the desired behavior. If you were to place a breakpoint on your `Console.WriteLine` call, you could verify in debug mode that `yPosition` has a value, and that the value it has is 1.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to print the value of yPosition:

```
Console.WriteLine($"y position is: {yPosition}");
```

The [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) method returns -1 if the character or string is not found in this instance. That is why, your variable `yPosition` should always have some int value.     You can check it if you set a breakpoint on the line:

```
int yPosition = book.IndexOf(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `Console.WriteLine`, you forgot to provide the format position for the `yPosition`. Change the line to following:

```
Console.WriteLine("y position is: {0}",yPosition);
```